# Remove space from the right side of an image in a nav-bar using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a simple main header which contains a navbar , I want to change the alignment of the right side of the image.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marketing-main-header_banner{
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8GY.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 900px;
    width: 1700px;

}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
        <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            
            </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what I have :
[image]

as you can see there is space on the right side of header and left side,  I want the image to float right side and remove that space on the right side, but left side should have that white space.

Here is what I want:

[image]

what am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use edge offset values on the `background-position` property.

By using a negative value we can offset the image further towards the right of the page, giving you the effect you are looking for.

Read more:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.marketing-main-header_banner{
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8GY.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right -190px bottom;
    position: relative;
    height: 900px;
    width: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
        <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kompetencje</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**By adding a couple div**

Added marketing-main-header_banner_image to hold the image that can be bigger than marketing-main-header_banner.

Added nav-holder to place the navbar-toggler button in the correct place.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  width: 1700px;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner_image {
  overflow: visible;
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8GY.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  width: 2000px;
}

.nav-holder {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  width: 1700px;
  width: 1700;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
  <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
    <div class="marketing-main-header_banner_image">
      <div class="nav-holder">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Faq</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kontakt</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Kompetencje</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```